# accessing json input with laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I am using restangular to post a request to users/login

my laravel route is like so

```
Route::post('users/login', array('as' => 'login', function () {
    $input = Input::all();
    return Response::json($input);
}));
```

the data in the post header is formatted like so

```
{"input":["username":"un","password":"pw","remember":false]}
```

this dosn't work either

```
{"username":"un","password":"pw","remember":false}
```

this route is returning an empty array [].  I am guessing my input is formatted incorrectly as from the laravel docs

> Note: Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the
>   application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like
>   normal.

edit: it is working with this input ie. no quotes

{username:un,password:pw,remember:false]}

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$input = Request::json()->all();
```

---

You can test it by returning the array directly from your route:

```
Route::post('users/login', array('as' => 'login', function ()
{
    $input = Request::json()->all();

    return $input;
}));
```